# Why use the pack() method in another line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, methods, tkinter

I have a quick question regarding why I should use `.pack()` in another line.

Example:
If I call the `Label` function as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="Sample Text").pack()
```

it has the same effect in [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter) as:

```
label = tk.Label(root, text="Sample Text")
label.pack()
```

But as soon I want to configure the label later on, the first example dosen´t work:

```
label = tk.Label(root, text="Sample Text").pack()
label.config(bg="YELLOW")
```

raises an:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'
```

This is fixed as soon I write the `pack()` function in a separate line:

```
label = tk.Label(root, text="Sample Text")
label.pack()
label.config(bg="YELLOW")
```

Why is [python](/questions/tagged/python) behaving like that?

Answer (score 1):

Because:

1. *All* methods return something, be it `None` or some other
   particular object.
2. `call1().call2().call3()....calln()` returns whatever `calln()`
   supposed to return.
3. left-hand side of an assignment (`lh = rh`) is assigned whatever
   expression(if any) in the `rh` returns.

`grid`, `pack`, `place` are all *methods* on [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter) widgets that return `None` (the default return value when the absence of an actual `return` statement).

Here's a very similar behavior:

```
def return_a_list():
    return [0, 1]
rh = return_a_list().append(3)
lh = rh
input(lh)
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with return values. If you're chaining statements, then your return value is going to be whatever the last method in the chain returns. `Label()` returns a label object. `pack()` returns `None`. You can imagine now what the error "**None**Type object has no attribute 'X'" actually means.

So, the solution is, use `Label()` and save the object to a variable. Then, call the method `pack()` on the object. `pack()` still returns `None`, but the `label` variable is not overwritten with `None`. It still contains the label object.

Edit: I figured I'd elaborate a bit.

All functions in python return a value, even if this is not done explicitly. When you write a function like

```
def return_something():
    return "some value"

return_value = return_something()
```

then the `return_value` variable will refer to a string with text "some value".

Consider a function that does not return anything like so

```
def return_nothing():
    print "No values returned in this function"

returned_value = return_nothing()
```

The `return_nothing()` will have return value of `None` and that's the value that will be assigned to `returned_value`. If you had anything in there before, it will be gone.

When doing method chaining like you do in your `Label().pack()` example, what you're actually doing is calling the method `pack()` on the object that is returned by `Label()`. The final return value of the chain will be whatever the last method returns. `pack()` returns nothing, so the return value is `None` and that's what is assigned to the variable `label`. However, if you end the chain with `Label()` then the return value is a label object and that's what goes in `label`. When you call `pack()` on a separate line, the return value `None` is discarded (it does not overwrite the label object inside `label`).

Hopefully that's a little more clear :)

Comment: Really helped me a lot. Thanks Buddy